# Making a class testable

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, internal

So I have a class called `User`. It has an `internal` constructor. I want to create a `User` object though so I can mock it like this:

```
public ISessionManagerInstance MockedSessionManager()
{
    var manager = new Mock<ISessionManagerInstance>();
    var company = new Chatham.Web.Business.Classes.Company(500, "", "", Enumerations.WebRelationshipInfo.NotSet, "", 0, 0, Data.Login.TeamOwnership.NotSet, 0, 0, false, null, false);
    manager.Setup(p => p.Company).Returns(company);

    Chatham.Web.Business.Classes.User displayUser = typeof(Chatham.Web.Business.Classes.User);
    displayUser.EntityID = 1786;
    manager.Setup(p => p.DisplayUser).Returns(displayUser);

    return manager.Object;
}
```

Now, `Company` has a constructor, so that's easy. But `User` has one that's only internal. Is there any way I can create a `User` and just set one `int` property on it so I can pass that object back on the mock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

create an `IUser` interface, have User implement it and create mocks against it. This is a very common practice in the world of .NET testing. All of your methods that use Users will mostly likely need to now accept `IUser` references.

Another possibility (which I don't recommend, but it's there) is to use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) assembly attribute. Then the internals of your production assembly can be visible from your test assembly.

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you recommend against using InternalsVisible to?  We use it all the time in our UnitTest assemblies. They are the only assemblies that our main assemblies expose their internals to and they are not compiled or shipped with release builds so I am wondering what the aversion to it is? Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: It's just personal preference. Maybe I should have left that out of my answer. I can understand the benefit of `InternalsVisibleTo`, but I personally feel it shouldn't be necessary. I can see how people could make a good case for why it's useful/good.

Comment: I think there are cases where it is necessary. Certainly interfacing out your classes and mocking to the interface is valid solution and can work in many cases however there are cases where and interface isn't possible or isn't desirable and in those cases InternalsVisibleTo is the right way to go IMO. You gave a solid complete answer suggesting both approaches.

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to add your Unit Test Project as an "internal to" of your main project, this allows your unit test code access to things marked "internal" without allowing anyone else to do so. Its a simple thing to implement in the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
// main project AssemblyInfo.cs file 
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourProject.Tests")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) property in your AssemblyInfo.cs to make internal members visible to your UnitTest assembly.